# EF7 rc1 Upgrade from Beta 6: Invalid column name

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

After upgrading from Beta 6 to RC1 - Final I get the following errors:

SqlException: Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
Invalid column name 'Enabled'.
Invalid column name 'Slug'.
Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
Invalid column name 'ThemeId'.
Invalid column name 'Content'.
Invalid column name 'DisplayInNavigation'.
Invalid column name 'Dynamic'.
Invalid column name 'Enabled'.
Invalid column name 'Layout'.
Invalid column name 'LinkText'.
Invalid column name 'Order'.
Invalid column name 'Slug'.
Invalid column name 'Title'.

This is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PageContent](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Content] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Created] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DeletedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DisplayInNavigation] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Dynamic] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Layout] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LinkText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Modified] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Order] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Slug] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ThemeId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PageContent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

and my Migrations:

```
   migration.CreateTable(
                name: "PageContent",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Content = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Created = table.Column<DateTime>( nullable: true),
                    DeletedDate = table.Column<DateTime>( nullable: true),
                    DisplayInNavigation = table.Column<bool>( nullable: false),
                    Dynamic = table.Column<bool>( nullable: false),
                    Enabled = table.Column<bool>( nullable: false),
                    Layout = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    LinkText = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Modified = table.Column<DateTime>( nullable: true),
                    Order = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Slug = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_PageContent", x => x.Id);
                });

   migration.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "ThemeId",
                table: "PageContent",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);
```

Comment: Anyone got any idea?